# How to automatically change name if sql table exists after running the code in python?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run this code once a day to log the dataframes to make historical dataset.

I have connected mysql with pymysql to save my pandas dataframe into mysql using pymysql and converted pandas dataframe into sql using .to_sql method.

However, if I run this code 2 times, the name of the table overlaps and won't run 2nd time.
Therefore I need to change the name(data_day001, data_day002, data_day003...) of the table each time I run this code.

```
# Credentials to database connection 
hostname="hostname"
dbname="sql_database"
uname="admin"
pwd="password"

# Create SQLAlchemy engine to connect to MySQL Database
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}"
                .format(host=hostname, db=dbname, user=uname, pw=pwd))

# Convert dataframe to sql table                               
channel_data.to_sql('data_day001', engine, index=False)
```

Please advise me how I could solve this problem.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: save numer in file - and next time read numer from file, add 1, and save it back in file. And us e this this number to generate name  `f"data_day{number:03}"`

Comment: Make the date part of the name, like `data_22020511`?

Comment: @furas that is exact approach I am looking for but I don't know how I could apply it on the to_sql() name instance. `channel_data.to_sql(f"data_day{number:03}", engine, index=False)` like this?

Comment: @snakecharmerb that would be even more ideal, actually.

Comment: Use `inspect` to do that. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`inspect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/inspection.html) function:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

def get_table_name(engine):
   names = inspect(engine).get_table_names()
   return f"data_day{len(names):03}"

engine = create_engine(...)

channel_data.to_sql(get_table_name(engine), engine, index=False)
```

After some days:

```
>>> inspect(engine).get_table_names()
['data_day000', 'data_day001', 'data_day002', 'data_day003', 'data_day004']
```